# What function do i have to use in wordpress im making a plugin

Tags: wordpress

What function do i have to use in wordpress to trigger my function.
for example i have a page Home and About me  when i click the home page it will call my function and display it in the content area and also the same when i click about me it will call my function about me and display something in the content area?
Please help me with this im stuck here dont know what wordpress function to use.

mr problem is how can i put the post id or slug in my function when i click one the pages that i create.

```
function get_page_content($page_id_or_slug) {
    if(!is_int($page_id_or_slug)) {
        $page = get_page_by_path($page_id_or_slug);
        $page_id_or_slug = $page->ID;
    } 
    $page_data = get_page($page_id_or_slug); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', viewitem());
    return $content; 
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: anyone wants 2 help with this please. . . .